# How to achieve UV coordinate animation in three.js?

Tags: three.js

Is there a way to achieve uv coordinate animation/morphing for vertices in a manner similar to morphTargets which works for position attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. There is no difference between the position attribute and the uv mapping attribute from a webgl viewpoint. Anything that you want to do or can do to one, you can do to the other.

Comment: The morphTargetInfluences[] in Mesh only seem to work on the position attribute of its geometry. Hence, I do not see a way to animate uv attributes in geometries without changing shader code.

Comment: I think you may need to post more code. As is, this answered your question, which is pretty generic. Since three.js has a shader interface, you are free to write anything you want. I imagine that this is not the answer you're looking for, but for something less generic you would have to provide some code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the example that follows - I would like the colors attribute to "morph" to morphColors depending on the morphTargetInfluence. https://codepen.io/champati/pen/zLBjzK?editors=0010